# Using laptop vga port, misunderstanding

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga

I'm wondering if a VGA Monitor connected to the laptop, will act exactly as the inbuilt monitor?
More specifically:

1. I have the monitor connected to the laptop via VGA port.
2. I Start the laptop.
3. On Laptop's screen I see the Boot Screen, but on the VGA monitor I can't see anything until the OS system is loaded.

**So the questions are:**

1. What if I disconnect the inbuilt laptop's display, and connect the VGA monitor only, and boot? Would my laptop work 100% as if it was connected to its own display. Even without any OS ?
2. Is the VGA port controlled by the mother board or by the OS.

#### I know that on desktop motherboards which have embedded video card, there is no functional difference between using a PCI-express Video vs Embedded

Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK the primary display is used as the boot-time display. The multiple window functionality is not supported by the motherboard OR the BIOS. That is why the VGA monitor doesn't fire up until after the OS has booted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What if I disconnect the inbuilt laptop's display, and connect the VGA monitor only, and boot? Would my laptop work 100% as if it was connected to its own display. Even without any OS ?

As I understand from [these](https://www.pcspecialist.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?3706-Bios-loads-on-second-monitor-instead-of-primary) [three](http://www.sevenforums.com/graphic-cards/195001-windows-7-booting-secondary-monitor.html) [forum threads](http://www.overclock.net/t/1101757/dual-monitor-issue-on-boot-up), the display output ports are prioritized internally, perhaps in [north-bridge chip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northbridge_(computing)) (assuming you don't have integrated graphics like Intel HD series). And by 'prioritized internally' I mean you can not change it through BIOS options or from OS settings. Therefore, unless you disconnect your primary, in-built display, VGA output won't be able to take over the displaying task, meaning that the secondary display will not kick in until after the OS starts.

> Is the VGA port controlled by the mother board or by the OS.

It's connected to either south bridge or north bridge, as seen in the wiki page I provided above.

Comment: Good question, made me wonder about how things worked and influenced me for a quick research:)

Answer (score 2):

Some laptops switch primary output to the VGA port when you close the lid. There is a small magnet enclosed in a display frame. Closed lid is detected by a sensor (called HAL or HALL sensor), usually located near the speaker assembly, which detects magnetic field produced by the magnet when the lid is closed.

Try to start the laptop, close the lid right after that, and check if you can see BIOS on the external monitor.  Alternatively, you can try to fool the sensor, by placing a small magnet next to it (you can find exact location of HAL sensor in hardware maintenance manual for your model).

Comment: Quite interesting solution :)

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on what output is connected to which CRTC (display controller) on the GPU. They're identified by an ID, according to the hardware design, and the 0 should be connected to the LVDS (internal display) on a laptop, and the 1 to the VGA/whatever output. By default, the output occurs only on CRTC 0 on laptop but for many desktop configuration, output is the same on all the CRTCs.
After that, the display driver take control, and should (if everything works as expected) detect connected monitors (and their specs by EDID) and configure appropriatly the outputs. If no display is connected on LVDS but there is one detected on VGA, it'll be the primary and the only display.

But it only applies in the case of modern GPU having multiple CRTCs. On very old laptop, you can only have one or the other display working, or both displaying the exact same thing. They can be configured only in "clone" mode, and as far as I know it's a BIOS switch which control the routing.

Answer (score 1):

I have an older Dell laptop in which I have experienced a similar situation.
The back light on the built in screen is dead, so I needed to use an external monitor.
With the internal monitor connected, it produced the same results as you describe; the bios and POST info (presumably) shows on the internal screen but not the external, and nothing shows on the external screen until windows loads to the desktop.
However once I unplugged the integrated screen, I do now see the bios and POST on the external VGA connected monitor.

So I'd say give it a try. 
It may differ from device to device if/how it will work, but trying it shouldn't hurt anything.